# How can I teach Exeggcute Egg Bomb?

Tags: pokemon-black-white

The TM for Egg Bomb is not in Generation V, and that is the only way Exeggcute can learn Egg Bomb! Can I possibly teach Exeggcute?

Comment: If I recall, exeggcute doesn't learn Egg Bomb, but Exeggutor does on level 31 - you may need to evolve exeggcute before 31, or possibly take it to the move relearner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The TM for Egg Bomb is not in Generation V

Well, that's strange, since Egg Bomb was only a TM in the Generation I games; Red, Blue and Yellow!

And you cannot have a Pokemon from that far back of a game, which thus means that it's impossible to get an Exeggcute with Egg Bomb. Exeggutor however learns it at level 31 in Generation II and III games and at level 27 in later games.

So, either you evolve the Exeggcute before that level, or evolve it later and make it learn it through the move relearner.